# Shopware 6.5.4.0 snippet name shows when empty

Tags: twig, shopware6

I would like to use a snippet to determine the content of an element and if the snippet is empty, the element should not be displayed.

But if the snippet is empty its own name is always displayed as a string.

I have been able to solve this with a replace to get the snippet empty during the check but I would like to solve this a little more elegantly does anyone have a better idea?

Here is my code:

```
{% set header_areaButton = 'header.area_button' | trans | raw %}
{% if header_areaButton | replace({'header.area_button': ''}) != '' %}
    <div>{{ header_areaButton | raw }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: FYI:  Using the filter `raw` when using (the compact) `set` has no real value as the variable will be treated as unsafe anway - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/yxk9h6)

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it a little bit better now:
{% set header_areaButton = 'header.area_button' %}
{% if header_areaButton | trans != header_areaButton %}
  <div>{{ header_areaButton | trans | raw }}</div>
{% endif %}